# Как проверить, что пользователь написал?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

пишу FSM, хочу проверить сообщение

```
if "что здесь написать" == "да":
    I= I+1
```

Comment: Пишите как тут: https://aiogram-birdi7.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html

Comment: Посмотреть как это делается в документации...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async def check_emp(message: types.message):
   if message.text == 'твой текст':
       do_something()
       
    
def register_handler_other(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(check_emp)
```

Не забывай про await.